# New Facebook Messenger integration doesn't support URL Scheme Suffix?

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger

I'm developing a 2nd version of our app for Facebook Messenger to meet their new platform integration requirements described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger

I'm attempting to allow both apps to share the same Facebook App ID. This page from the iOS troubleshooting docs has a section on **Sharing an app ID across Apps**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#testsharedialog

It shows you how to add URL Scheme Suffixes to your apps so that they can both live on the same phone yet share the same Facebook App ID.

I've done this and it works successfully so that both apps can use Facebook login without stepping on each others toes.  However, it seems that doing so **broke my integration with FB messenger**, which was previously working.

After following the instructions on the troubleshooting link above and adding the fields for the URL Scheme suffix, the videos I send to FB messenger no longer have a Reply button on them. Media inside Messenger that was sent from my app no longer contains any tappable element that takes you back to my app.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get the URL Scheme Suffix working in a way that it still works with the new Messenger Platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heard back from Facebook directly on this. Their response:

No it doesn't. Because we will try to open the scheme without suffix. How would we know which suffix you want to open from messenger? ... So no suffixes are not supported. Just use a different app id.